# Flex Alive PDF - Print dialog not opening up in MAC

Tags: apache-flex, alivepdf

We had a requirement in flex (flash builder 4), where we need print the component and generate the pdf document and open up the print dialog box.

For generating pdf from flex i used AlivePDF library. In the library itself we have a option

pdf.addJavaScript("this.print();");

When we added the above code, i can see the dialog box in windows machine in all the browsers (IE, Firefox, chrome). But when i test it in Mac (safari or Firefox), iam not able to see the dialog box opening.

Please let me know, is there any workaround for the above problem.

Thanks in Advance,

Regards

Srini